# ncsrf token missing / ajax django integration /

Tags: python, ajax, django

I made a ajax login , ajax logout and ajax signup form using django as you can see here.

This is the live site where you can test it

http://192.241.153.25:8000/ (this isn't my IP address)

And I have inserted {% csrf_token %} in each of the form.

But for some reason, after I login, the log out doesn't work with the following error

[22/Jul/2016 23:26:26] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /logout/
[22/Jul/2016 23:26:28] "POST /logout/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2274

I have tried so many different methods and I don't know why the token is missing.

I also checked the browser and found out the token is working.

Also, what doesn't work is signup part.

I did add a user avatar field, but ever since then, the sign up doesn't seem to be functioning.

Another thing is, I want to make the logout button (#logout_form) appear only when the user typed in the right info, and doesn't appear when users type in the wrong id or password.

also, i want to show an error text when users type in the worng information.

could anyone help me figure out how to do this?

thanks.

here is my scrips inside the index.html

```
          <script>
          $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings){
  if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
  }
});
          $('#logout_form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault()

              $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: '{% url 'logout' %}',
                data: $('#logout_form').serialize(),
                error: function(response){
                  $('.login_bar').text(response.error)
                },
                success: function(response){
                  console.log(response);
                  $('.login_bar').text(response.sucess)
                  $('.login_bar').html(response.error)
                // do something with response
             }
            });

          });

            $('#login_form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault()

                $.ajax({
                  type:"POST",
                  url: '{% url 'login' %}',
                  data:$('#login_form').serialize(),
                  error: function(response){
                    $('.login_bar').text(response.error)
                  },
                  success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    $('.login_bar').html(response.username)
                    $('.login_bar').html(response.username)
                    $('#logout_form').toggleClass(show)
                  // do something with response
               }
              });

});


            $('#signup_form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault()

                $.ajax({
                  type:"POST",
                  data:$('#signup_form').serialize(),
                  url: '{% url 'signup' %}',
                  error: function(response){
                    $('.login_bar').text(response.error)
                  },
                  success: function(response){
                    <!--console.log(response);-->
                    $('.login_bar').text(response.success)
                      $('.login_bar').text(response.error)
                  // do something with response
               }
              });

            });

          </script>
```

views.py

```
        from .models import UserProfile

    def ajax_signup(request):
        form = UserSignupForm(request.POST or None)
        pform = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid() and pform.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            profile = pform.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()

            new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
            login(request, new_user)
            data = {'form': form.cleaned_data, 'success': 'success'}
        else: data = {'form': form.cleaned_data, 'error': form.errors}

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')

    def ajax_logout(request):
        logout(request)
        data = {'success': 'successfuly logged out'}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

mode.spy

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="You/media/uploads", blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
        from django import forms
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model, login, logout

    class UserSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
        email = forms.EmailField(label='Confirm Email')
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = [
                'username',
                'email',
                'password'
            ]
        def clean_email(self):
            email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email_qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
            if email_qs.exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError("This email has already been registered")
            return email



    from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions
    from .models import UserProfile

    class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = UserProfile
            fields = ['avatar']

        def clean_avatar(self):
            avatar = self.cleaned_data['avatar']

            try:
                w, h = get_image_dimensions(avatar)

                #validate dimensions
                max_width = max_height = 100
                if w > max_width or h > max_height:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(
                        u'Please use an image that is '
                         '%s x %s pixels or smaller.' % (max_width, max_height))

                #validate content type
                main, sub = avatar.content_type.split('/')
                if not (main == 'image' and sub in ['jpeg', 'pjpeg', 'gif', 'png']):
                    raise forms.ValidationError(u'Please use a JPEG, '
                        'GIF or PNG image.')

                #validate file size
                if len(avatar) > (20 * 1024):
                    raise forms.ValidationError(
                        u'Avatar file size may not exceed 20k.')

            except AttributeError:
                """
                Handles case when we are updating the user profile
                and do not supply a new avatar
                """
                pass

            return avatar
```

Comment: http://www.wierdsource.com/posts/form-submission-with-ajax-in-django/

Comment: Have you tried adding csrf token to your ajax data like `data: { "csrfmiddlewaretoken": $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(), }` ?